# Python: Have correct image url, cannot download image

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting the correct url for the image. But I can't seem to be able to download the image and save it to a file. I am new to python so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I have tried this with several other article sources and haven't had any trouble downloading the image once I get the url. Guess it doesn't like africom?

```
url: http://www.africom.mil/Newsroom/Article/12058/multinational-participation-plays-key-factor-to-exercise-african-lion

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

links = soup.find("div", {'class': 'usafricom_ArticlePhotoContainer'}).find_all('img', src=True)
for link in links:
        imgfile = open('%s' % timestamp + "_" + title.encode("utf-8") + ".jpg", "wb")
        link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1]
        imgurl = "www.africom.mil" + link + ".jpg"
        download_img = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()
        imgfile.write(download_img)
        imgfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the error you are seeing with your code. Your question does not mention the error. When I tried your code, I hit this error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: www.africom.mil/Image/12059/High/030414-M-XI134-002.jpg
```

This error is because of this line in your code:

```
imgurl = "www.africom.mil" + link + ".jpg"
```

It does not specify the http protocol. Change it to:

```
imgurl = "http://www.africom.mil" + link + ".jpg"
```

and check. It worked for me with this change.

Comment: I was getting no error readout. The img file would just be empty. Thanks for taking the time to check it out.